# Defining macros with multiple bracket fields in LaTeX

Tags: macros, latex

I try to define a macro in LaTeX that would use two arguments enclosed in brackets, like the frac command of the math environment, or the textcolor command do : `\frac{4}{5}`.
I tried something like

```
\def\desc #1\}\{#2 {\textcolor{red}{\textbf{#1}} \emph{#2}}
```

but it doesn't seem to work.
Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LaTeX way of defining a new macro is with [`\newcommand`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Macros).  There is an optional argument to specify the number of arguments.  The syntax is

```
\newcommand{name}[num]{definition}
```

Remember that `\newcommand` must appear in the preamble before `\begin{document}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\desc}[2]{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{#1}}~\emph{#2}}
\begin{document}
\desc{This}{is how it looks}
\end{document}
```

Build it and you get something like

[image: This is how it looks]

Using [`\def`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/def) is the TeX command for making a macro.  Stick to the LaTeX commands unless you really know what you're doing.

---

There a [TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) that is better suited than Stack Overflow for LaTeX questions.

Answer (score -1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand{\txtsc}[2][red]{\textcolor{#1}{\textbf\emph #2}}
\begin{document}
\txtsc[red]{is how it looks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: can you please add an explanation for why this answers the question?

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality and are more likely to attract upvotes